# Model of Mosfet Switching in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I would like to perform a simulation on LTspice about a switching MOSFETs.

In particular on how the parasitic inductance and capacitance affect the switching transient.

In order to perform this analysis I need a MOSFET model of SCT3022AL from Rhom semiconductor.

Following the link:
https://www.rohm.com/datasheet/SCT3022AL

Unfortunately it is not avaiable the LTspice model of this MOSFET.

I could create my own model but I saw that the information needed are:

- L (channel    length)
- W (channel    width)
- VT0   (zero-bias  threshold   voltage)
- KP    (transconductance,  μn/pCox)
- LAMBDA     (channel-length    modulation  coefficient,    λ)

These information are not avaiable in the datasheet.

How can I do to create my own model? Alternatively, do you know if this model is avaiable?

Thank You.

Comment: In particular, you need the additional gate-drain overlap capacitance, to model the Miller Effect, where switching is delayed if you have high Rsources, as gate charge is transferred onto the Drain.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to create a model. You can download the finished model from the manufacturer's website.

https://www.rohm.com/products/sic-power-devices/sic-mosfet/sct3022al-product/documents

In the "Design Model" section are files for Spice to download.

If you do not know how to add a model, here is an example post about it on my blog:

http://sigaris-electronics.eu/2018/11/ltspice-adding-an-element-model-to-the-schema/

Answer (score 0):

But these basic model parameters dos not include any information about the parasitic inductance and capacitance. Are you aware of this?

Also, you can download the model directly from Rhom sie.

https://www.rohm.com/products/sic-power-devices/sic-mosfet

And if you find some time you can try to watch this: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eE-8Q0vPUak